# Form self submittin variables lost

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have an form that I want to submit to the same page (index.php) and I want to use the entered information to be a javascript variable

```
<?php $loginid = $_POST[username] . $_POST[password]; ?>
```

Basic code

```
<script> var pass= "<?php $loginid; ?>"; </script><script src="functions.php"></script>
```

More code

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="passcheck ()">
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <input name="password" type="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And then in the js file:

```
Function passcheck () {
    If pass=="blablabla"{
        document.getElementById('id').innerHTML= "welcome blabla!"
    }else {
        window.alert("wrong username/password")
    }
}
```

And when I log in with blabla's "account" i see for a breef second welcome, blabla!, bet then it dissapears. Does anyone know how to fix it? I tried e.i. on the html tag `onload="passcheck ()"`  but that doesn't work either.

When I put an onclick event on a random element with tge checkpass function, it works, so how do I cal that function after the file has reloaded?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) Show all the code

Comment: ` document.getElementById('id').inberHTML` ==> ` document.getElementById('id').innerHTML`

Comment: Sounds like the form is submitting. Since you don't have an action attribute on the form tag, it will submit to the page it is on. (To test this, add `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` to the top of the page)

Comment: That typo doesn'matter

Comment: When I put var_dump($_POST); in the php area, i get an output of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be `.innerHTML` not `.inberHTML`